# how to get sub groups from security group in active directory c#

Tags: active-directory

I have security groups in Active Directory account. Security groups have users and also sub groups. I able to get users from Security groups .Here is the code for getting users from security group and I passed "groupname" as parameter.It will return corresponding users belong to group.

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable(groupName);
        var _with1 = dt.Columns;
        _with1.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("AccountDisabled", typeof(bool));

   using (DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword))
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry))
        {
        searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN={0}))", groupName);
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        object members = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Invoke("Members", null);
        //<<< Get members

        //<<< loop through members
        foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
        {
            DirectoryEntry currentMember = new DirectoryEntry(member);
            //<<< Get directoryentry for user
            if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "user")
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                dt.Rows.Add(props1["sAMAccountName"].Value, props1["givenName"].Value, props1["sn"].Value, props1["displayName"].Value, props1["mail"].Value, Convert.ToBoolean(currentMember.InvokeGet("AccountDisabled")));
            }

        }
```

But I have no solution to get subgroups that added in Parent security groups.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me...

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(groupName);
    var _with1 = dt.Columns;
    _with1.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
    _with1.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    _with1.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    _with1.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
    _with1.Add("Email", typeof(string));
    _with1.Add("AccountDisabled", typeof(bool));
    _with1.Add("Groups", typeof(string));

    using (DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword))
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry))
        {
        searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN={0}))", groupName);
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        object members = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Invoke("Members", null);
        //<<< Get members

        //<<< loop through members
        foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
        {
            DirectoryEntry currentMember = new DirectoryEntry(member);
            //<<< Get directoryentry for user
            if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "user")
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                dt.Rows.Add(props1["sAMAccountName"].Value, props1["givenName"].Value, props1["sn"].Value, props1["displayName"].Value, props1["mail"].Value, Convert.ToBoolean(currentMember.InvokeGet("AccountDisabled")),"");
            }
            else if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "group")
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                //foreach (var group in result.Properties["member"])
                //{
                    dt.Rows.Add("","","","","",false,props1["name"].Value);
                //}
            }
        }
   }
```